# How to prevent the user from exiting the channel during splash screen

Tags: brightscript

I am a beginner Roku developer.

I have removed the splash screen from the manifest and created a separate component that has an animation and serves as a splash screen before proceeding to the channel UI. My task is OK but I have to make it impossible for the user to get out of the channel with the back button.

I thought to do it with onKeyEvent but don't know what to make it do when the user presses the back button...

```
function onKeyEvent(key as string, press as boolean) as boolean
    handeled = false
    if press then
        if (key = "back") then

        end if
    end if
end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All You need to make it impossible for the user to get out of the channel with the back button is a handle back press on the tree root, in the scene script.
Just like you described.

```
'inside scene.brs
function onKeyEvent(key as string, press as boolean) as boolean
    handled = false
    if press
        if (key = "back")
            handled = true
        end if
    end if
    return handled
end function
```

Comment: Yes, i figured it out but thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
function onKeyEvent(key as string, press as boolean) as boolean
handled = false
if press then
    if (key = "back") then
        handled = true
    end if
end if
return handled
```

end function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).